# Adding styles to Parameters controls in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I am new to SSRS. 
We are building reports in **BIDS 2008** and hosting them on **Share point**. 
There are different parameters for these reports like Regions/Districts, Start Date and End Date, Which by default shown as Dropdowns and Calendar controls by **SSRS**.

Is there a way we can add styles to parameter pane, parameters?
And also add validations to Calendar controls?

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: There aren't built in styling options for parameters. Validation can be done with SSRS functions or in your query depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try hacking the css in the report manager - not sure if that will 'pass through' to sharepoint.  Maybe you could modify some css in sharepoint to this.  Use a dom inspector such as Firebug, Chrome developer tools or IE developer tools to see where the styles are coming from.

If you need to validate dates, you can do this in a stored procedure. Check the values of the parameters and kick out an error message.  It's not pretty, but it works.

```
IF DATEDIFF(m,@STARTDATE, @ENDDATE) > 0
     RAISERROR(N'Date range must be less than one month',16,1)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that modifying the css is most likely not supported and may be wiped out at any time by service packs and hotfixes!

Comment: Editing the CSS for Report Manager will have no effect on SharePoint as they are unrelated - Report Manager is for Native mode report servers, Sharepoint mode does not use Report Manager. Possibly you can modify the Sharepoint UI somehow but I'm not sure how. The only way to gain the kind of control over parameter input that is being asked about here is to build a custom UI that integrates with the Reporting Services web service.

Comment: Thanks for the support. We ended up using Iframe on a webpage. Everyone is happy :)